# Have Chitauri been in Marvel movies?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

The Chitauri made the scepter that Loki used to carry the Mind Stone around in *The Avengers* movie. The Chitauri also made a weapon that Ned and Peter Parker played around with in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.

**Have Chitauri themselves been in any Marvel movies?  If so, which movies and which characters?**

Comment: They kinda invaded New York.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Chitauri are the alien fleet in *The Avengers* that Loki leads in the invasion of New York. All the Chitauri parts that we see in *Spider-Man: Homecoming* were salvaged from the alien wreckage of that battle.

[image: Close up of a Chitauri flying around the skyscrapers of New York, others are seen following behind]

---

The Chitauri in the MCU are roughly taking the place of the Skrull race, since I believe Fox has the rights to the Skrull as part of their Fantastic Four deal.

None of the Chitauri were ever individually identified. Their leader during the invasion was Loki, and their "boss" was Thanos. The Chitauri themselves were nameless drones (literally -- since they are some type of cybernetic race, when their mother ship is destroyed they all shut down.)

As far as I am aware, other than the appearance in *Avengers*, every other reference to the Chitauri in the MCU (movies or television) has been by name or "archive footage"; we've never seen a living Chitauri before or since. There was, however, one in *Guardians of the Galaxy* in The Collector's museum:

[image: A Chitauri drone sits in a glass display case with its knee risen in the Collector's museum]

Comment: Actually Marvel shares the rights to the Skrulls, like the Watchers and the Maximoff twins. They just don't have the rights to the Super-Skrull (or Uatu the Watcher). So they used the Chitauri for other reasons, perhaps so they could be shut down all at once.

Comment: The one in the Collector's museum is why I am giving+1 in addition to simply marking this as the accepted answer. ... I think that the reason I did not remember is that they did not have speaking roles.

Comment: @JDoe I believe there are "limits" to what they can do with the Skrull in the MCU as well; but yes, they also didn't want to waste a big enemy as cannon fodder either.

Comment: @KutuluMike I can't find it at the moment, but I do remember having seen a vid on youtube from this years SDCC (I've watched so many of them so I can't recall which one it was anymore) where Kevin Feige stated that - I think - *Captain Marvel* will be set in the 1980s (or something along those lines) and be the first MCU movie to feature the Skrulls...

Comment: That's possible; _Avengers_ was a long time ago (in movie terms) and _Fantastic Four_ didn't do well; Marvel may no longer be worried about what Fox may or may not want to do with them in the future (as opposed to e.g. having two Quicksilver/Scarlet Witch characters)

Comment: @KutuluMike Besides not having the rights to Super-Skrull, what are those limits? Marvel plans to use the Skrulls in the Captain Marvel movie, which doesn't suggest any limits to me.

Comment: The [exact quote](http://www.ifc.com/2012/05/kevin-feige-captain-america-2-the-skrulls-the-avengers) from Feige was: “Skrulls have a big connection to ‘Fantastic Four.’ So there are some contractual limitations about who can do what when it comes to Skrulls". I don't know anything beyond that.